# c# do while loop any word that start with y triggers the y/n check and ruins the loop

Tags: c#, do-while

I was trying to make a simple program that asks the user whether or not they want to input their name.
I used a do-while loop to do this. If the answer is 'y', the program prints text and asks the user for a name. If the answer is 'n', text is printed. In both cases, the loop ends. If the user input anything other than 'y' or 'n', the loop repeats and asks for a proper input.
My problem is whenever someone inputs any string beginning with the letter 'y', for example 'yes' or 'yeetjasdk'. When this happens, the code prints text to ask the user for a proper input, however, the loop exits and the program ends. This does not happen for words starting with 'n'.

```
do  {                                                                           //Keep running loop until user
            Console.Write("Welcome. Do you want to tell us your name? (y/n): ");    //enters either y or n.
            answer = Console.ReadLine();                                             //Ask user for input.
                if (answer == "y") {
                    Console.Write("What is your name: ");
                    userName = Console.ReadLine();  
                    Console.WriteLine("Welcome, {0}", userName);
                }
                else if (answer == "n") { Console.WriteLine("Acknowledged."); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't catch that."); }
        } while((result = string.Compare(answer, "y", true)) < 0 || (result = string.Compare(answer, "n", true)) < 0);
```

Comment: Is there some reason you need to accept a string here? It sounds like [`Console.ReadKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.7.2) might be better suited for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line seems truly bizarre to me:

```
while ((result = string.Compare(answer, "y", true)) < 0 || (result = string.Compare(answer, "n", true)) < 0);
```

`string.Compare()` performs a greater than/less than/equal comparison based on the sort order. That doesn't seem like what you want.

Why not use something far simpler? Such as:

```
while (answer != "y" && answer != "n")
```

Or better yet, exit the loop as soon as you know the answer is valid. That way you don't have to check the condition twice, and you ensure your logic is consistent.

```
while (true)
{                                                                                         
    Console.Write("Welcome. Do you want to tell us your name? (y/n): ");
    answer = Console.ReadLine();
    if (answer == "y") 
    {
        Console.Write("What is your name: ");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();  
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome, {0}", userName);
        break; // <-- exit the loop
    }
    if (answer == "n")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Acknowledged.");
        break;  //<-- exit the loop
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I didn't catch that."); }
}
```

Comment: The break code actually seems a lot nicer. Thanks! I'm new to coding so my stuff is pretty brute force haha